# Php - how to remove/delete tag with specific string in QueryPath?

Tags: php, xml, nodes, querypath

How to filter the node that has a certain string inside it and `Delete` or `Remove` it.

Something like

The `XML` is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <user>

        <urls>
          <link>www.weblink-1.com</link>
          <link> www.weblink-2.com</link>
          <link> www.weblink-3.com</link>
          <link> www.weblink-4.com</link>
          <link> www.weblink-5.com</link>
        </urls>

    </user>
```

Let's say I want to remove/delete `<link> www.weblink-4.com</link>` using `QueryPath` how do you achieve that?

> I tried something like:

```
 $r= qp($path,'user')->find("urls>link")->
 filter("link:contains('<link> www.weblink-4.com</link>')");
 print  "<h1>".$r."</h1>";

 ///***ERROR: Catchable fatal error: 
 Object of class QueryPath\DOMQuery could not be converted to string*
```

> I have also tried something like:

```
 $r= qp($path,'user')->find("urls>link:contains('<link> www.weblink-4.com</link>')"); 

 print  "<h1>".$r."</h1>";


 ///***ERROR: Catchable fatal error: 
 Object of class QueryPath\DOMQuery could not be converted to string*
```

> And then something like:

```
 $qp =  qp($path,'user>urls>link')->filter("link:contains('<link> www.weblink-4.com</link>')")->remove();
$qp->writeXML($path);   

   ///This Deletes the entire Document's nodes leaving only the *<?xml version="1.0"?>*
```

This should be simple but turning to be rather very stressful..... Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, QueryPath became kinda stressful. I got some hint from: 
@Paul Crovella ... And rather I used:

```
$path = "../ntmhp/prdat/".$userId."/xmls/rf/rss.xml";
            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->load($path);

            $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

            foreach($xpath->query('//link[contains(., "www.weblink-4.com")]') as $node) {
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
            }

            $dom->save($path);
```

This was fast and effective.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

filterPreg works alright for me.

```
$elements = htmlqp($page, 'user urls linky');
$filtered = $elements->filterPreg("/www.weblinky-[^4].com/");
echo count($filtered ); // 4
```

Although.. I think it will require   looping though the $filtered elements to reconstruct the HTML, which isn't ideal IMO..

Comment: Thanks though I get WARNING: `Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in...`

Comment: I am using older (2.1) version of QP, so that could be the cause of the difference...Different delimiters for filterPreg , like "#www.weblinky-[^4].com#" could also be tried.

Comment: Am now facing a different issue... May b u can help... See link::: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957442/php-xpath-apppendchild-not-working-properly